# how to perform unit testing jersey webservice

Tags: web-services, unit-testing, jersey-2.0

Actully I am trying to test my Jersey web service with the jersey test framework. the web server I am using is Websphere 7 and java version 6. This is my project requirement I cannot upgrade the java version .

My issue is how to build the unit test for my web service . I want to test them on WebSphere but I am not sure how do I setup the environment for unit testing like junit .

more specifically I just need to call an URL from the test class and check the response. But how to call the URL from the test class on the websphere I am not getting direction for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html).

First thing you need is one of the [Supported Containers dependencies](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html#d0e17030). Any of those will pull in the core framework e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then you need a test class that extends `JerseyTest`. You can override `Application configure()` to provide a `ResourceConfig` as well as any other providers or properties. For example

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    public String get() { return "hello"; }
}

public class TestResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
        config.register(TestResource.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void doTest() {
        Response response = target("test").request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("hello", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

You should visit the link provided to learn more and see more examples.

Comment: In your above example I stuck with using it on websphere server could you please tell me how do I make sure that it runs on websphere ?

Comment: It's a (JUnit) unit test. It does not need to run on a server (meaning you don't need to even start your sever. The test is independent of any installed server. It starts it's own standalone server). Add the container dependency in a test scope. Then create the test where all your other unit tests go, then run it the same way you run your other unit tests

Comment: Actually I have resource config property configured on server how do I pass these property value on the test class if I don't use the server ?also on your second point "add the container dependency in the test scope " could you please let me know how do I do that .sorry to ask you dump question but your direction is helping me

Comment: Just use `config.property("....", value)`. _"add the container dependency in the test scope "_. See `<scope>test</scope>` (above) in Maven dependency so it doesn't get bundled with your app

Comment: thats perfect !! one more last question for this moment what is the meaning of  config.register(TestResource.class); what does this register method do

Comment: You are registering your resource class to test. You are basically configuring an application from scratch with the `ResourceConfig`. You can register all the classes in a package by using `config.packages("thepackage")` or you can register your resource classes individually. So you can create a different test class for each resource class if you want.

Comment: I see your delete post with the exception. Jersey 2.19 is compiled with Java 7. If you can't switch to Java 7, then try an older Jersey version, like 2.6 (I think it is compiled with Java 6)

Comment: I have external  Jar which has the interfaces when I run the test it showing me noclassdeffound error for the interfaces which is there in the jar .how can i include interfaces in the jar in my test ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you are talking about

Comment: for instance I have resource.java which has couple of webservice method in the method I am using some claseses which is there in the xyz.jar . those clases are not avalible when i am runing mavan install its giving me

<error message="com/abnamro/pbi/conversations/IPBIConversations" type="java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError">java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/abnamro/pbi/conversations/IPBIConversations

IPBIConversations is the name of interface